# discord.py master(v2.0) -- What's default value for a FlagConvert object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-3.9

My problem is i can't find a default value for `FlagConvert` if the previous parameter of `FlagConvert` has a another default value.
For example:

```py
class ClearFlag(FlagConverter, prefix='--', delimiter=':'):
    has: str = None
    match: str = None
    by: Tuple[Union[User, Member], ...] = None
    check_all: bool = True


@command('clear', aliases=['cls', 'clean'])
async def clear_messages(ctx: Context, limit: int = 10, flags: ClearFlag = ???):
   ...
```

In docs examples on [commands.html](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/commands.html#flagconverter),
always `FlagConvert` is required and I can't find any answer.

I use discord.py v2.0, so you need these:

- [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/)
- [Installation](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py#installing) (install the **development version**).
- `discord.ext.commands.FlageConvert` on [API Refrence](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html#flag-converter) and [Commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/commands.html#flagconverter)

Comment: well, what do you want it to be?

Comment: an object from which all the attributes in the flag class can be accessed .

Comment: but if it's an optional argument what should the default value be? You can simply create an empty instance.

Comment: None or utils.MISSING, tnx for your help

Comment: I wrote the code in the hope that there is a default for this value, and if it is not so, it will take a long time.

Comment: I can use it, tnx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use `ClearFlags` object. because has all of attributes I need. For example:

```py
@command('clear', aliases=['cls', 'clean'])
async def clear_messages(ctx: Context, limit: int = 10, flags: ClearFlag = ClearFlag()):
   ...
```

But should never be a `type`